# Restarting a Timer

Tags: c#, datagridview, timer

I am working on a C# project and I have some troubles  with code (below). When I run the project, Timer Tick event seem to repeat itself, it just does what is signified by the comments, I go prone, then I stand back up, I want it to repeat itself so I continuously stand up and go prone, and yes in the datagridview "on" Selection I have `timer1.Start()`;

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Countername++;
        switch (Countername)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                PS3.SetMemory((0x01786718 + (uint)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index * 0x5808), new byte[] { 0x01 });//Go Prone
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                PS3.SetMemory((0x01786718 + (uint)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index * 0x5808), new byte[] { 0x00 }); // Stand Up
                break;
            }

            if (Countername == 2)
                Countername = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will Tick periodically until you Stop it. Have you actually set a breakpoint (or added a [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx)) to confirm that the timer is or is not firing? Or perhaps is the timer firing periodically, but your code just not functioning correctly?

Comment: My timer works just once, it doesn't repeat itself as i would like it to. In my case, what i am doing, i go prone, stand up, but then it doesn't re-execute again.

Comment: Yes, you already said that, and ignored what I just asked. Have you **confirmed** that the function is not being called again? Or are you just **assuming** that it is not, because the end result is not as expected? *Again*, set a breakpoint and/or add a debug print.

Comment: @Wire you are issuing a `break` before the counter variable value is reset, hence it works only for the first time.

Comment: I am assuming that it is not being called again, because the end result is not what is expected, like you said timers go until told to stop, i never told it to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer is not working as there are logical issues in the code, as the timer will never reach

```
if (Countername == 2)
{
    Countername = 0;
}
```

because a `break` is applied before the value is reset to zero.

The better way to write your code would be

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Countername++;
    switch (Countername)
    {
        case 1:
            PS3.SetMemory((0x01786718 + (uint)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index * 0x5808), new byte[] { 0x01 });//Go Prone
            break;

        case 2:
            PS3.SetMemory((0x01786718 + (uint)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index * 0x5808), new byte[] { 0x00 });//Stand Up
            if (Countername == 2)
                Countername = 0;

            break;
    }
}
```

One more thing to be noticed is :

if for some reason the value of `Countername > 2` then the it would not enter any of the block of switch statement.